# php imageflip() usage with mpdf

Tags: php, image, mpdf, strpos

I have to flip image of product to print on pdf if customer choose right side(default is the left side). I have 392 products with diffrent pictures but have only left side photos. I'm using mpdf and the product side is written in title(string) of the product like
$productName = "Product x - left side";
 or
$productName = "Product x - right side";

My code now is:

```
<?php 
$img = ".'/images/model/'.$photo.";
if (strpos($productName, 'right') == true){
   $img=  imageflip($img, IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL);  
} ;?>

     <img src="<?php $img; ?>"  alt="Radaway Sp. z o. o." />
```

I'm not a php pro so give me a hint if you found some bug ;)

Comment: `$img = ".'/images/model/'.$photo.";` Huh..... ?? Surely that is not right?

Comment: And where do you get `$photo` from?

Comment: Welcome. To ask On Topic question, please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: $img = "/images/model/".$photo; - that's better?

Comment: Yes or `$img = "/images/model/$photo";`

Comment: I get $photo in one of other files(from CMS) that's not made by me. I'm starting with this <img src="./images/model/<?php echo $photo ?>"  alt="Radaway Sp. z o. o." /> and that print me the photo of the left side product on pdf at the moment. I have to flip photo if customer choose right side.

Comment: Another file? Does `$photo` actually exist in this file. Check it by doing an `echo $photo;`

Comment: $img = "/images/model/$photo";   ?> <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" now it's give me the good photo of the product but it's left photo and it's no matter what side of the product is choosed.

Answer (score 0):

Now the img concatenation is fixed the strpos also need a little correcting

As `strpos()` can return false when the string is not found and a number when it is found, but if it is found starting in column 0, a zero equates to false as well, this is a better way of coding `strpos()`

```
<?php 
$img = "/images/model/$photo";

if (strpos($productName, 'right') !== false){
    // !== false so it must have found the string `right` in $productName
    $img=  imageflip($img, IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL);  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!!

RiggsFolly thanks for your involvement. Change side of the photo I code(with little help of Senior) like this:

```
function flipPhoto($img, $side){
$i = null;

$imgR = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);

if ($side == 3){
   imageflip($imgR, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);  

    ob_start(); 
    imagejpeg( $imgR, NULL, 100 ); 
    imagedestroy( $imgR ); 
    $i = ob_get_clean(); 
} else {
    ob_start(); 
    imagejpeg( $imgR, NULL, 100 ); 
    imagedestroy( $imgR ); 
    $i = ob_get_clean(); 
}


return $i;}

            $img = __DIR__ . "/../../images/model/$photo";

            $i = flipPhoto($img,$product['side_id']);
                ;?>
        <!-- photo --> 

        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode( $i ) ?>" alt="Radaway Sp. z o. o." />
```

I write the flipPhoto function couse I'm flip photos in few places(shopping card/pdf etc.)